# Fdisk showing wrong SD card size

Tags: fdisk, cache, partition-table

So I've been formatting and reformatting a couple SD cards as I'm running some tests and I need to reformat pretty often however every time I plug a different card in fdisk reports the old cards capacity.

For instance let's say I have a 128GB a 64GB and 32GB card. If I use fdisk to format the 64GB card and then try to format the 128GB fdisk will show the card has 64GB, up to the point where I create the partition table, print it out before writing and notice that half the capacity is gone.  This is mitigated by quitting and running fdisk again, at wghich point it will report the correct size.  But now if I just formatted the 64GB card and plug the 32GB in then fdisk returns `fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error` I have to quit out of fdisk and run fdisk again at which point it will report the correct capacity.

Now normally this isn't really an issue but because I'm reformatting these cards a considerable amount I want to automate this by creating a script that does everything for me, but this reporting of the wrong size is preventing me from automating this task. The cards being reformatted aren't being plugged in in a consistent order/sequence either so I can't take that into consideration and account for it.  Is there anyway to clear the cache of fdisk or something along those lines so that it reads the card size every time I plug a card in rather than going off of the size of the previous SD card that was plugged in?

Comment: It would help to know how you access those SDcards. Is it a real hardware MMC bus socket or do you use some USB card reader, which typically pretends to be a USB mass storage device and will not tell the host if the SDcard has been replaced.

Comment: It is a USB card reader.  So that's probably my issue right?  Is there anyway to force it to check the size somehow?

Comment: Yes, I expect this to be the problem. I don't know how to reset such a reader, bacause I simply pull the reader out and plug it in again. As this is no option in your case, I suggest to search for how to reset the reader. Maybe unloading the driver and reloading it would help?